# How to Add/Inject/Create a Razor functionality tag (@Html WebViewPage)

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How does one inject or add functionality to **@html (WebviewPage class)**

For example you have basic functionality in MVC view

```
    //typical example
    @model  ProjName.Models.Contacts
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }
    
    @Html.RenderPartial("_WhateverView",model)
```

What i am trying to accomplish is add a typed custom functionality such as (**DoCustomOutput**)

```
   //Goal to get something simple as DoCustomOutput
   @model  ProjName.Models.Contacts
   @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }
        
    @Html.DoCustomOutput(model) //this would output custom stuff html
```

Or even better

```
   //Goal to get something simple as DoCustomOutput
   @model  ProjName.Models.Contacts
   @{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
   }
            
   @HelperLib.DoCustomOutput(model)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first option you need to create an extension method for the [`IHtmlHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ihtmlhelper?view=aspnetcore-7.0) type. The method should return [`IHtmlContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.html.ihtmlcontent?view=aspnetcore-7.0) or any of its derived classes:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlContent DoCustomOutput(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, object model)
    {
        return new HtmlString("<p>Hello, World!</p>");
    }
}
```

The second option is very similar. The only difference is that you don't have access to the `HtmlHelper` object:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;

public static class HelperLib
{
    public static IHtmlContent DoCustomOutput(object model)
    {
        return new HtmlString("<p>Hello, World!</p>");
    }
}
```